# IOS: test app old device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I create an app I want to test my app on old devices (i.e. iOS 3.0).
Can I set up the simulator with older versions of iOS to test my app?

Comment: what stops you from testing your app on 3.0 target?  there can be differences b/w simulator and actual device. I strongly suggest you to test with actual device if you are planning to support old devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the hardware the iOS simulator simulates, but only if you have the old version of the SDK installed. You can do this by choosing the menu `Hardware` -> `Version` and then the 3.x version you want.

Please note this is not the recommended way! The simulator is nice for quickly testing some new features, but the simulator has bugs and other major differences. So test your App always on a iOS 3 device.

Get a first generation iPhone to test on or grab an iPhone 3G and downgrade it to iPhone OS 3. It's not supported by Apple, but [Google](http://www.google.nl/search?rls=en&q=downgrade%20iphone%20to%203.1.2) will help you on downgrading an iPhone to OS 3.

Comment: +1 Yes, test on device, it's a simulator not an emulator. Just for cost savings, if you don't need the ad ons (telephony, camera, etc) a first or second generation iPod touch will allow most testing too.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the version in the iOS Simulator.

Hardware -> Version -> []